# Jrobin vs rrd4j

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have to use any of java implementation of rrd.

I have been going through rrd4j and jrobin but not sure sure which one to use.

So can anyone let me know the difference between rrd4j and jrobin?

--
Mini

Answer (score 1):

They're both very close and share a common code base. rrd4j forked a few years ago. The main difference is the license : Apache for rrd4j vs LGPL for jrobin.

There is a few performance improvement in rrd4j: a more scalable pool, a more efficient file format for rrd.